# Logic needed to reverse an array when there are non empty, continuous elements

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of **size 5** that I need to reverse the values based on what is non-empty.

Where the non-empty values are continuous but they can come in any index: 
For example I could have 3 non-empty values:

```
c[0], c[1], c[2] or 
c[1], c[2], c[3] or
c[2], c[3], c[4]
```

or 4 of them coming in any order..

```
c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3] or
c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4] or
```

I need to reverse the array only when the values are non-empty.
So in case 1 I will have 
c[2], c[1], c[0] and so on.

Case will have c[3], c[2], c[1] and so on..

The number of elements that are non-empty and the array is dynamic and generated off a request.  I cannot shift the elements to start with index 0 as some outside code relies on the index. All I have to do is reverse this array and send it back.

I am trying to use a hashmap to mark the indices, and mark the number of non-empty elements in the array. Not sure how to proceed after this, any ideas will be appreciated!

```
     HashMap<Integer, String> myHash = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 

        for(int i = c.length-1; i<=0 ; i--)
            {
                    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(c[i]))
                    { 
                        countNonEmpty++;
                        myHash.put(i, c[i]); //We need to mark the index and decrement by the countNonEmpty
                       }                
            }


get the first hash element - 
Iterator iter   = myHash.keySet().iterator(); 
 while(iter.hasNext())  
             {
                 Integer correctIndex = (Integer) iter.next();

//But all I need is the first element in hashMap to decide how to set the reverse array's index.           
       if(myHash.size() - correctIndex < 0 )  //This means it will have to be 0 to index for array
                  {  
                     //What is the right index for c[] 
                       c[correctIndex - myHash.size() + 1 ] = myHash.get(correctIndex);
                      continue;
                  }
                  else if(myHash.size() - correctIndex == 0)
                  {   //What is the right index for c[]
                       c[correctIndex - myHash.size() + 1 ] = myHash.get(correctIndex);
                      continue;    
                  }
```

Comment: So you're saying that the non-empty elements are all clustered together, surrounded (potentially) by empty elements?

Comment: yes, they can be placed anywhere in my array of size 5, not just starting from index 0, but they're continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick demonstration of a solution that makes use of `java.util.Arrays` and `java.util.Collections` to do the swapping.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Reverse
{
    static String[] inputArray = new String[5];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        inputArray[2] = "John";
        inputArray[3] = "Sally";
        inputArray[4] = "Fred";

        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = inputArray.length;

        boolean foundStart = false;
        boolean foundEnd = false;
        System.out.println("before sort");
        for (int index = 0; index < inputArray.length; index++)
        {
            System.out.println(inputArray[index]);

            if (!foundStart && inputArray[index] != null)
            {
                startIndex = index;
                foundStart = true;
            }

            if (foundStart && !foundEnd && inputArray[index] == null)
            {
                endIndex = index;
                foundEnd = true;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nafter sort");
        List<String> swapList = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(inputArray, startIndex, endIndex));
        Collections.reverse(swapList);
        System.arraycopy(swapList.toArray(new String[swapList.size()]), 0, inputArray, startIndex, swapList.size());

        for (int index = 0; index < inputArray.length; index++)
        {
            System.out.println(inputArray[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will this approach also work if I have only one non-empty element in index 4, i.e c[0] to c[3] are empty and only c[4] has a value. I don't need to swap in that case c[4] with c[0] as I don't swap non-empty values. So I just retrieve c[4] as is.

Comment: Yes, it'll work with just c[4] populated, although it might be a bit "dumb" in that case.  It would be easy enough to simply return as soon as you determine your array to be sorted only contains one element.  The code in my answer is a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) so you should be able to play with it to see what happens.

Comment: yes I would just add a check to see if the startIndex == endIndex and in that case we know there is going to be just one element and we can skip additional swapping.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any auxiliary data structures:

1. Find the indices of the first and the last non-empty elements by scanning the array from the start and from the end.
2. Swap the first and the last element.
3. Increment the first index, and decrement the last index.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 while `first_index < last_index`.

Comment: I'm going to try this approach. thanks. Will post some code if I get it working.

Comment: I wish I could mark more than one answer. I would have marked this but the other answer had sample code and more explanation. thank you though!